# How to update two models using one django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am facing one issue with django forms

Here is my model :

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class UserProfile(AuditFields):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    joining_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

I need to create a form for editing profile details of the current user

This is my form. But it is a model Form so only getting the detauls from the User Profile table only

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']
```

How can I get first_name ,  last_name from User table and save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the fields as a [**`CharField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField) in form, and use [**`cleaned_data`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) attribute to fetch the data and save it:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.user.first_name
            self.fields['last_name'].initial = self.instance.user.last_name

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']

    def save(self, commit=False):
        instance = super().save(commit=True)
        user = instance.user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: It's working 

But I am facing one more issue 

When I click that form I am getting all the field values but not getting the first name and last name

Comment: I am calling the forms like this 

form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_profile)